# How set minClusterSize in google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, markerclusterer, google-maps-ios-utils

In Android SDK there is minClusterSize property that when we set it to 1 it show's every elements as cluster not marker.
But in iOS SDK doesn't exist minClusterSize and DefaultRenderer by default show's lower than 3 items as items not cluster.
There is any solution ?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: But why using cluster if you want to show every single marker on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class CustomClusterRenderer: GMUDefaultClusterRenderer {

    let GMUAnimationDuration: Double = 0.5
    var mapView: GMSMapView?

    override init(mapView: GMSMapView, clusterIconGenerator iconGenerator: GMUClusterIconGenerator) {
        super.init(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        self.mapView = mapView
    }

    func markerWith(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, from: CLLocationCoordinate2D, userData: AnyObject, clusterIcon: UIImage, animated: Bool) -> GMSMarker {

        let initialPosition = animated ? from : position
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: initialPosition)
        marker.userData = userData

        marker.icon = clusterIcon
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        marker.map = mapView
        if animated {
            CATransaction.begin()
            CAAnimation.init().duration = GMUAnimationDuration
            marker.layer.latitude = position.latitude
            marker.layer.longitude = position.longitude
            CATransaction.commit()
        }
        return marker
    }

    func getCustomUIImageItem(userData: AnyObject) -> UIImage {
        if let item = userData as? Marker {
            return item.merkerIcon
        }
        return UIImage()
    }

    override func shouldRender(as cluster: GMUCluster, atZoom zoom: Float) -> Bool {
        print("Zoom Level is \(zoom) , and result is \(zoom<=14)")
        return zoom <= 14;
    }


}


class Marker: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {

    var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var estate: Estate

    init(estate: Estate) {

        self.estate = estate
        self.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: estate.latitude,longitude: estate.longitude)

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add one line on class GMUDefaultClusterRenderer.m

```
 static const NSUInteger kGMUMinClusterSize = 10;
```